# Comparing a string with an object in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
function printAll(strs: string | string[] | null) {
  if (strs && typeof strs === "object") {
    for (const s of strs) {
      console.log(s);
    }
  } else if (typeof strs === "string") {
    console.log(strs);
  }
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

Here I have broken the big if statement into two parts as follows.
The ... show the part that I am not referring to.

I can understand that here `if ( ... typeof strs === "object") {` we are comparing the type of the variable because it can contain other types too.

I do not understand this: `if (strs === "object" ... ) {`. What is the purpose of this statement?

Comment: please re-read your question, seems like you have a typo and it's not clear what you are asking

Comment: Where is `if (strs === "object") {`?

Comment: `if (strs && typeof strs === "object")` is saying "if `strs` is truthy *and* `strs`'s type descriptor is `"object"`". the double amerpsand (`&&`) delimits the two conditions.

Comment: Like mentioned, your question is slightly muddled.  But I'm assuming your asking why the `if (typeof strs === 'string')`, and not just use `} else {`,.. It's because `strs` could still be null.

Comment: @FelixKling I got your point now. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (strs && typeof strs === "object")
```

is **not** the same as

```
if (strs === "object" && typeof strs === "object")
```

which is what you seem to be thinking. It's equivalent to

```
if (Boolean(str) && (typeof strs === "object"))
```

Why is it necessary to check whether `str` is a "truthy" value? Because `typeof` returns `"object"` for two data types: Object values and Null values (i.e. `null`):

```js
console.log(typeof {});
console.log(typeof null);
```

So if you only did  `if (typeof strs === "object")`, `strs` could still be `null` and therefore the `for` loop would fail (or in this case TypeScript would complain).

The code could have been written as

```
if (strs !== null && typeof strs === "object")
```

to be more explicit.

Comment: `strs !== null` doesn't eliminate `undefined`

Comment: @CallumMorrisson: True, but that should already be a compile time error because the type of `strs` is `string | string[] | null`.

Answer (score 1):

I've re-ordered the code a little and added some comments. Hope it answers you question:

```
function printAll(strs: string | string[] | null) {
  // handle the null case
  if (strs == null) {
    return
  }

  // handle the string[] case
  if (typeof strs === "object") {
    for (const s of strs) {
      console.log(s);
    }
    return
  }

  // if we reached this point strs is a string, we could check here if (type strs === 'string') but it's redundant
  console.log(strs);
}
```

Comment: It's not equivalent to the original code though. The case where `str === ""` is different.

Comment: I would also recommend `Array.isArray` instead of `typeof x === "object"` for checking if something is an array

Comment: I wanted to stay close to the OP's question

Answer (score 1):

```
function printAll(strs: string | string[] | null) {
  if (strs && typeof strs === "object") {
    for (const s of strs) {
       console.log(s);
    }
  } else if (typeof strs === "string") {
    console.log(strs);
  } else {
    // do nothing
  }
}
```

In the printAll function, you can pass inputs as string, string[], or null

```
let fruits: string[] = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana'];
printAll(fruits);
let fruit: string = 'peach';
printAll(fruit);
```

So in case of string array type of strs is object and in the other case its string as expected.